# error C2664: 'wsprintfW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I copied some code from a VC6 project to a vc++2010 project, but the code cannot be compiled.
 the error is **'wsprintfW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPWSTR'**, problem code is:

```
inline bool RingCtrl::BuildPathAndName(char* pBuf, int bufSize, int8 priority, int idxNumber) const
{
    wsprintf(pBuf, "%s\\R%u%06x.DAT", _directory, (int)priority, idxNumber);
    return true;
}
```

the `wsprintf` is defined in `wmcommn.h` like below:

```
WINUSERAPI
int
WINAPIV
wsprintfA(
    __out LPSTR,
    __in __format_string LPCSTR,
    ...);
WINUSERAPI
int
WINAPIV
wsprintfW(
    __out LPWSTR,
    __in __format_string LPCWSTR,
    ...);
#ifdef UNICODE
#define wsprintf  wsprintfW
#else
#define wsprintf  wsprintfA
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building your program with `UNICODE` defined (default in VC++2010), while it was not defined in VC6. When `UNICODE` is defined `wsprintf` takes `wchar_t*` instead of `char*` as a first parameter (and `const wchar_t*` instead of `const char*` as a second one).

Easy solution would be to explicitly call `wsprintfA` instead of `wsprintf` in `RingCtrl::BuildPathAndName`, but in this case you'll have a problems with Unicode file names. You'll probably have a lot of other similar errors connected to `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`, so you may want to change your project settings in VC++2012: Project Properties->General->Character Set->Use Multi-Byte Character Set.

Correct solution would be to move from `char*` to `wchar_t*` (or even better to `TCHAR*`), but that would probably require a lot of effort.